# Show existence of element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field with infinitely many elements and let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$ such that there are finitely many intermediate extensions $L_1, \ldots , L_m$.

Show that there is an element $\theta\in K$ such that $F(\theta )=K$.

As a hint we have to use the following statement:

Let $F$ be a field with infinite elements and $V$ a $F$-linear space of dimension $n$ and $W_1, \dots, W_m$ subspaces of $V$ of dimension $n_i<n, i=1, \dots, m$. Then $V \setminus{(W_1 \cup \cdots \cup W_m)} \neq \varnothing$.

Could you give me a hint how we could use that statement?

Answer (score 0):

The $L_i$ are $F$-vector subspace and $K-\bigcup L_i=C$ is not empty. Let $c$ in $C$, $F(c)$is a subfield distinct of any $L_i$,since $c$ is not an element of an $L_i$, so it is $K$.

Comment: So, we have that $F(c)\subseteq K$, or not? It is left to show that $K\subseteq F(c)$ to get the equality. Could you give me a hint for that? @TsemoAristide

Comment: $F(c) $ is not one of the $L_i$, so since it is a field it is $K$.